# Using Solarized 'high' diffmode with vim-fugitive 'Gdiff'

Tags: vim, solarized

I'm using the main [Solarized](https://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/) colour scheme without any problems but when using [Gdiff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-working-with-the-git-index/) from vim-fugitive the high contrast diff mode is not selected. I've placed the following in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
let g:solarized_diffmode="high"
```

however the standard colour scheme is still used even when in the diff mode triggered by `:Gdiff` on a file with changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I need to set the diffmode option *before* calling the colour scheme. As described in the [vim-colors-solarized README](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized/blob/master/README.mkd) under "Advanced Configuration":

> Set these in your vimrc file prior to calling the colorscheme.

Which also includes the diffmode. So the snippet above needs to be

```
set background=dark
let g:solarized_diffmode="high"
colorscheme solarized
```

With `colorscheme` called *after* setting the diffmode.